# Cgicc embed image- cgi thinks image is script

Tags: html, c++, image, cgi

I'm building a simple CGI application using Cgicc. I'm trying to embed an image in my page, however, this is the error returned from CGI

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2014 13:26:52] code 403, message CGI script is not executable ('/cgi-bin/tmp3.jpg')
```

I'm invoking an instance of a CGI Server using

```
andrew@ubuntu:~/www$ python -m CGIHTTPSever
```

The C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cgicc/Cgicc.h"
#include "cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h"
#include "cgicc/CgiDefs.h"
#include "cgicc/Cgicc.h"
#include "cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h"
#include "cgicc/HTMLClasses.h"
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

try{
    Cgicc formData;
    cout << HTTPHTMLHeader()<<endl;
    cout << HTMLDoctype(HTMLDoctype::eStrict)<<endl;
        // Set up the HTML document
        cout << html() << head() << title("Cgicc example") << head() << endl;
    cout << body().set("bgcolor","#cccccc").set("text","#000000").set("link","#0000ff").set("vlink","#000080") << endl;

    cout << img().set("src", "tmp3.jpg").set("height", "100").set("width", "100");

    cout << "<form method=\"GET\" action=\"formProcessor.cgi\">"<<endl;
    cout << h2("Input picure info") <<endl;
    cout << p("Height")<<endl;
    cout << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"height\"> <br>"<<endl;
    cout << p("Width");
        cout << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"width\"> <br>"<<endl;
    cout << "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">"<<endl;
    cout << "</form>"<<endl;


}catch(exception& e){
cout  <<"Error"<<endl;
}



  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know the solution to this issue? I haven't been able to find much online regarding this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue here was not with the code, but rather the directory that I was storing the image. I was trying to serve the images from the `cgi-bin` directory, which was causing the server to interpret it as a CGI script. I changed this line:

```
cout << img().set("src", "tmp3.jpg").set("height", "100").set("width", "100");
```

to this

```
cout << img().set("src", "/images/tmp3.jpg").set("height", "100").set("width", "100");
```

and it began serving the images properly. The line

```
cout << img().set("src", "tmp3.jpg").set("height", "100").set("width", "100");
```

was being called from the url

```
http://0.0.0.0:8000/cgi-bin/myCGI.cgi
```

so without the absolute URL the image was being mistaken for a CGI Script.